# memory_limit php.ini vs ini_set('memory_limit','4096M')

Tags: php, memory-limit

I had a debate with my boss.

Which one is more convenient, efficient, standard.

Do we apply memory_limit in php.ini
or
do we just insert a code in php files like this
`ini_set('memory_limit','4096M');`

Which kind are you?

Comment: Ask your boss if he prefers to give an open, uncontrolled bulk budget for any and all expenses, or if it's better to allocate separate budgets in proportion to reasonable needs.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `memory_limit` in `php.ini` file will change it for all your PHP scripts running on that executable.

Using the `ini_set` will modify the configuration only for the script in which it is called and will end with the completion of the script's execution.

In a nutshell, the first one is a system-wide permanent change and the other one is a local to script change only during runtime.

Ref: [PHP: ini_set - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), [PHP Memory limit increase](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214893937-Increase-the-PHP-memory-limit)

Comment: yea but which one will you use?

Comment: that depends on what you want to do. If you want all your PHP scripts to have an increased memory limit, use the `php.ini` option. If you want only the current script to have a higher memory limit, use the `ini_set` option.

Comment: @xprilion exactly. I think the key is in _do all your scripts need more memory_, or _do you have a particular case_. If you bump it up globally, because _one particular script needs a larger memory allocation_ e.g. due to parsing big data, you have more chances of rogue scripts munching up as much as they can.